# Firestore firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to query all data by _id in fields receiver ( as image below), I use firestore firebase. Can anyone help me?
[image]

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: i want to get list notifications by filed id in receiver! Can you help me?

Comment: Have you tried going through the docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to query documents for values nested in map fields, you can use dot notation to find that value:

```
firestore.collection("notifications").where("receiver.id", "==", x)
```

Comment: Hi thank you so much, i add _ likely firestore.collection("notifications").where("receiver._id", "==", x). and it's work

Comment: Great!  Now, on Stack Overflow, it's customary to mark helpful answers as correct using the checkmark button to the right of the answer.